# using insert in stored procedure with optional parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am somewhat new to writing sql, and I know I can write a stored procedure with optional parameters. How can I specify optional parameters, but enforce that at least one optional parameter is required. Is this possible?

I want to be able to use the stored procedure to insert a row into a log table where there are a number of type flags to show what kind of entry it is. Therefore at least one of the flags should be set to true(1).

Comment: Is this for MySQL or T-SQL? You've tagged the question with both.

Comment: Im creating a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server Management. Like I said, I'm kinda new to this. Feel free to edit the tags. To be honest, i didn't know and shotgunned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach in this case is to define only one parameter, for example an ENUM type, witch will represent "witch of the flags has to be set to true". It will not be an optionnal parameter, because at least one of your flags has to be set to true.
Flags columns in your log table have to be DEFAULT false or DEFAULT NULL.

You will use an IF statement in the procedure to set the appropriate flag to 1 in your inserted log values (you should declare a temporary variable for each flag and set the appropriate flag to 1).

(Additionnaly, if you want to constraint your log entries to have at least one flag to 1, you can write a before insert and a before update trigger.)

Comment: I actually thought of this after I posted. Thanks, I will most likely go with this approach.